# remove blank page and number from title page

Tags: titles

I have started on my own template and am a beginner in this. So far the code is very basic, I want to remove the blank page that is before my title page and the page number at the bottom.

```
\documentclass[10 pt, a4paper, leqno, oneside]{report}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[swedish, english]{babel}

\begin{document}

 \include{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

And `titlepage.tex` is

```
%titlepage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}
    \centering
%University logo
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{SU_logo.png}
    % \rule{0.4\linewidth}{0.15\linewidth}\par
   \par
   \vspace{3cm}
%Thesis title
    {\uppercase{\Large the title of my thesis project which may span multiple lines\par}}
    \vspace{2cm}
%Author's name
    {\Large Author\par}
    \vspace{5cm}
%Degree
    {\Large A thesis submitted for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy\par}
    \vspace{2cm}
    {\Large Examinor \par}
    \vspace{3cm}
%Date
    {\Large May 2015}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
%\clearpage
```

Comment: `\include` always issues a `\clearpage`, this will be the blank page, most likely. Try `\input{titlepage}`

Comment: See the FAQ [When should I use `\input` *vs* `\include`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/5764)

Comment: I checked your code -- your content of the titlepage causes too much height for the page --> it's shifted to the next page, regardless whether `\input` or `\include` is used

Comment: Yeah, changing to input gave the result. I can shift around the layout of the titlepage. How can I move the logo closer to the top edge?

Comment: Any comments on how to remove the page number  from the title page?

Answer (score 3):

The several `\vspace` commands look weird, however, here's a solution with `\newgeometry` -- change the actual spacing at will.

```
\documentclass[10 pt, a4paper, demo,leqno, oneside]{report}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[tmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[swedish, english]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\input{titlepage}

\newgeometry{tmargin=2cm}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

`titlepage.tex`:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begingroup
\centering

 % University logo
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{SU_logo.png}%
  % \rule{0.4\linewidth}{0.15\linewidth}\par

  \vspace{3cm}
%Thesis title
  {\MakeUppercase{\Large the title of my thesis project which may span multiple lines}}

  \vspace{2cm}
  % Author's name
  {\Large Author}

  \vspace{5cm}
  % Degree
  {\Large A thesis submitted for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy}

  \vspace{2cm}
  {\Large Examinor}

  \vspace{3cm}
  % Date
  {\Large May 2015}% % Do not delete the empty line!

\endgroup
```

[image]

Comment: I would not use uppercase letters. Perhaps small caps is much better